# Component update lifecycle ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Stuck with one problem.

I have parent component for example `<Parent />`. In render method of this parent component i'm rendering **cards** for example `<CardItem />`.

And in this `<CardItem />` component i have `<IconComponent/>`.

***So the main problem is:*** 
When i'm trying to use `componentWillUpdate / did` in `<IconComponent/>` i see props for all components.

For example I will render 5 `<CardItem />` components and once one of 5 components updated i will have **5** line's in my console log.

**Question**: How to catch only one component which was updated?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution can use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` as will be giving you the new `Props` as that component and can then do whatever ever you want.
for more detail check [react lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` => Will give me 5 lines too since i will get all properties for every component

Comment: do you share props from `parent` component with `<IconComponent/>`, and how you're updating that `component`, i'd like to see shared example.

Comment: We need more code to give you an answer this could be many possibilities that you're talking about. Are you mapping from an array ? .map(ele => CardItem}) ? If so pass the ele through into IconComponent.. <CardItem data={ele}/>